# Don't see bootstrap.min.css on node_module?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to do my first App (ToDo List) on React. Thus, I installed with npm bootstrap. I installed boostrap with all theirs dependencies (popper,jquery) with this command: npm install boostrap popper.js react-icons jquery --save. The modules have been installed well. Although, when I want to import boostrap.min.css , I don't see it on my Module Directory. I just see package.json and README.md . I try to clone the boostrap with github and insert boostrap.min.css manually but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I`m strongly recommend you [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) or [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) packages. Its adapted for the react and you will not have problems with dependencies

Comment: I tried it. It seems doesn't work again. I get this error: ./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './reactstrap/dist/reactstrap.full.min.js' in 'D:\to-do-list\src'

Comment: If you want to use bootstrap styles in reactstrap you also need to install bootstrap and after import it like this `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`